# GraphQL: multiple entities in same query succeeds but response is missing data

Tags: java, graphql, quarkus, microprofile, smallrye

I have recently started using the Quarkus SmallRye implementation of GraphQL, and I am encountering this error when running queries. Let's say I have the following query implemented (domain is changed and entities are not complete, for simplicity):

```
WorkContract(id: "personId") {  
  startDate
  endDate
  company {  
    name  
  }  
}
```

And this other query:

```
Person(id: "personId") {  
  id 
  name 
  addresses {  
    streetName
    house
    city
  }  
}
```

If I run each query separately, I get a successful response containing all the requested data for the provided personId. However, if I query them together like this:

```
query {
  WorkContract(id: "personId") {  
    startDate
    endDate
    company {  
      name  
    }  
  }
  Person(id: "personId") {  
    id 
    name 
    addresses {  
      streetName
      house
      city
    }  
  }
}
```

The query is executed but there is data missing in the response, namely the addresses field under Person is an empty array (when there are actually addresses stored in the database). This missing data issue happens for all subfields of Person that have nested fields (id and name are correctly retrieved). When debugging it in a unit test, all the data seems to be there in the intermediate POJOs for Contract and Person, so I have no idea why it goes wrong at the very end. Note that Contract and Person have independent repositories and resolvers.

Is this behavior expected? What are the correct steps when implementing the resolvers and repositories so that a query can combine multiple independent entities?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This should absolutely work and return subfields for `Person` on any GraphQL server implementation. Could this be a *smallRye*-specific issue with ganged queries? What happens if you reverse the order of the two queries when you gang them?

Comment: That's the strange thing indeed: when trying to reproduce it in a unit test, the order affects the output (if the Person query goes first, there's data missing, but if it goes last, it succeeds), but that doesn't happen when running the application itself (there's data missing either way). That's also made it harder to debug.